# Why can I not access the value of this pointer. Objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, reactjs, react-native, pointers

I want to access `YGNodeRef node` in the parameters of the RCTMeasure function. This is from the yoga files in react-native, RCTShadowText.m

```
static YGSize RCTMeasure(YGNodeRef node, float width, YGMeasureMode 
widthMode, float height, YGMeasureMode heightMode)
{
  RCTShadowText *shadowText = (__bridge RCTShadowText *) 
  YGNodeGetContext(node);
  NSTextStorage *textStorage = [shadowText buildTextStorageForWidth:width 
  widthMode:widthMode];
  [shadowText calculateTextFrame:textStorage];
  NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = textStorage.layoutManagers.firstObject;
  NSTextContainer *textContainer = layoutManager.textContainers.firstObject;
  CGSize computedSize = [layoutManager 
  usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer].size;

  YGSize result;
  result.width = RCTCeilPixelValue(computedSize.width);
  if (shadowText->_effectiveLetterSpacing < 0) {
     result.width -= shadowText->_effectiveLetterSpacing;
  }
  result.height = RCTCeilPixelValue(computedSize.height);
  return result;
 }
```

YGNodeRef is delcared in another class called Yoga.h.

```
typedef struct YGNode *YGNodeRef;
```

I can see the values of `YGNodeRef node` in the debugger, but I can not figure out how to access it's elements in code. The contents look like this:

```
(YGNodeRef) 0x150094a00
    > style (YGStyle)
    > layout (YGLayout)
    lineIndex = (uint32_t) 0
    > parent = (YGNodeRef) 0x15009e200
        ..... etc .....
    > context
```

I want access to the 'context' child to check if it is null or not, some help would be much appreciated. Or if you simply know the reasoning of why the context would be null that will also help me :)

I am new to Objective C, so my logic may be flawed.

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with react-native, but I do see in your code there is a `YGNodeGetContext(...)` method which appears to call `->getContext()` on the node ref: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/9a2026beb9e3dca32ad97fadfb1488ccb4c31284/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp#L149

Comment: I see this is helpful thank you, but what does return value of void* mean. I want to simply check if the context child contains any children or possibly is nil.